# How to use keycloak-admin-client with custom Keycloak provider

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I am building a docker image based on Keycloak 18 with my custom provider which uses Keycloak Admin REST Client. I figured that I need to bundle some dependencies as well so I created jar files with `maven-dependency-plugin` and included those as well.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS javabuild
ENV HOME=/home/app
RUN mkdir -p $HOME
WORKDIR $HOME

ADD pom.xml $HOME
ADD my-provider/pom.xml $HOME/my-provider/pom.xml

RUN mvn -pl my-provider verify --fail-never
ADD my-provider $HOME/my-provider
RUN rm -rf ${HOME}/my-provider/target
RUN mvn -pl my-provider install
RUN mvn -pl my-provider package


FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0 as builder
COPY --from=javabuild /home/app/my-provider/target/my-provider*.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/
COPY --from=javabuild /home/app/my-provider/target/dependency/*.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build


FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev", "--db=postgres"]
```

I have difficult time to understand what I should exactly provide and how.

I tried to use `keycloak-admin-client` directly and only add that as dependency and no transient dependecies as it seems that Keycloak already has these dependencies available as since Keycloak 17 they use Quarkus. I don't know much about Quarkus but looking into docker container files I found:

```
bash-4.4$ ls | grep "rest"
com.openshift.openshift-restclient-java-8.0.0.Final.jar
io.quarkus.quarkus-resteasy-2.7.5.Final.jar
io.quarkus.quarkus-resteasy-common-2.7.5.Final.jar
io.quarkus.quarkus-resteasy-jackson-2.7.5.Final.jar
io.quarkus.quarkus-resteasy-server-common-2.7.5.Final.jar
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core-4.7.5.Final.jar
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core-spi-4.7.5.Final.jar
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider-4.7.5.Final.jar
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider-4.7.5.Final.jar
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider-4.7.5.Final.jar
```

If I run my provider the following in my provider:

```
public class MyProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {
    private final Keycloak keycloak;

    public MyProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        RealmModel realm = session.getContext().getRealm();

        this.keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                .realm(realm.getId())
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .clientId("admin-cli")
                .clientSecret("...")
                .build();

        UserResource user = this.keycloak.realm(realm.getId()).users().get("admin");
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

I will get

```
Uncaught server error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Then I realized that maybe I should add `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client:4.7.5-Final` as well. Then I got

```
Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder
```

Then I tried to add resteasy-client dependencies as well so after adding `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-client-api:4.7.5-Final` I got

```
Uncaught server error: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.spi.ClientConfigProvider: org.wildfly.security.auth.client.spi.RESTEasyClientConfigProviderImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/client/config/ConfigXMLParseException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.client.config.ConfigXMLParseException
```

Then I realized that `keycloack-admin-client` actually relies on `resteasy-client` version `3.13.2.Final` and not `4.7.5-Final`. So I add these versions of `resteasy-client`, `resteasy-multipart-provider`, `resteasy-jackson2-provider` and `resteasy-jaxb-provider` and got

```
Uncaught server error: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory
```

And now I have no idea what to try next.

I found [this issue report](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6350) which talks about Resteasy version conflict between Keycloak Admin REST Client and Quarkus and it mentions there's another package called `quarkus-keycloack-admin-client`. So I added that as dependency and again I got:

```
Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/admin/client/KeycloakBuilder
```

also `quarkus-keycloack-admin-client` is dependend on Keycloak 17 so I am not sure if it's 100% compatible with 18.

So my question is how I should include `keycloack-admin-client` in my provider?

Answer (score 0):

My Problems are very similar and I will try to build a customized quarkus-keycloak-server (https://blog.codecentric.de/2022/05/keycloak-x-aber-sicher-ohne-bekannte-sicherheitsluecken/) extended with dependencies needed by my own extensions. I dont know, if this will lead to a running system, but I'll hope so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I created a Keycloak ticket here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/11973

I solved this problem by myself by adding this:

1. I overrode the `resteasy-client` with version 4.7.5.Final.

   ```
   <!--Keycloak-->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
       <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
               <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
               <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
               <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
               <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <!--Resteasy-->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
       <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
       <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
       <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
       <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. [Copied all third-party dependencies to `/providers` folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmA06.png)
3. Because I got errors looks like:

   Uncaught server error: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.spi.ClientConfigProvider: org.wildfly.security.auth.client.spi.RESTEasyClientConfigProviderImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor

   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.client.config.ConfigXMLParseException
4. I found the dependency for this class and add this, it works for me :)

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.wildfly.client</groupId>
       <artifactId>wildfly-client-config</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: This didn't worked for me am using keycloak version 20.0.2 quarkus dist.